# zabbix trigger expression : count not 60 over 24hours/1440minutes

Tags: zabbix

I  have this zabbix trigger. The expression is
`{reporting:aggr.processend.req.count.count(1440m,60)}=0`

I want to clarify if it will throw a error , if the count is not 60 over 1440minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count(1440m,60)}=0` means "alert if the number of times, the item was equal to 60 in the last 1440m, is zero"

you need `count(1d,60,ne)}>0` if you want "alert if the number of times, the item was different from 60 in the last day, is not zero"